# How to modify function params in a .lua script file

Tags: c++, lua

I have a .lua file as follows:

```
timeout = 3000
index = 15
function Test()
    A(index, timeout)
    B()
end
Test()
```

### A and B fuctions are implemented in the c++. It will be excuted with a 'luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");' in c++.But the timeout and the index will change at different times.
The question is how to modify the params in real time?

I'm going to write two c++ programs.First one is to sent .lua string to the sencond one. The second c++ program implemets the A and B and will dofile the lua script. But the timeout and the index will changes very often. How to do that?  My solution is to parse the index and timeout string ,then write the current value to the file in the first c++ program.Any better solution?

Comment: as is your post doesn't make any sense to me. please read [ask]. where do you want to modify those params? in Lua or in C++?  what do you mean with "real time" in this context? what problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: Is this script just for learning? Because for what it does there's no point doing that in Lua; you're just calling C++ functions from C++, so there's no reason to go through Lua for that, unless you want that to be an entry-point for user-scripting.

Comment: @Piglet  I'm going to write two c++ programs.First one is to sent .lua string to the sencond one. The second c++ program implemets the A and B and will dofile the lua script. But the timeout and the index will changes very often. How to do that? My solution is to parse the index and timeout string ,then write the current value to the file in the first c++ program.Any better solution?

Comment: Please read https://xyproblem.info/   So you want to modify 2 variables in a Lua script. I'm not sure what your problem is. Just edit the Lua script befor you execute it? The more interesting question is why you would use a Lua file to "communicate" between two applications. you should probably describe the problem you're acutally trying to solve

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I'm not sure whether it is clear now.Let me know if it is still hard to understand.

Comment: @Piglet The actual application scenario is more complex.First program may have multi lua script to send. The content of the script will change.The point of using scripts is to give testers the ability to modify them without having to write code. A program may have more than 10000 different indexs. To use file operation interface?

Comment: `timeout` and `index` should be upvalues.  The second app should parse strings received from the first app and convert them to Lua values storing in those upvalues, after that invoke `Test.lua`.  The text of `Test.lua` should stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying a lua script over and over to call `A` with different arguments, you should probably just list all arugments in a single script.

```
local listOfIndices = {1,5,23,124,25,}
local timeout = 3000
for _,index in ipairs(listOfIndices) do
  A(index, timeout)
  B()
end
```

Otherwise having 10000 different indices will result in 10000 file write and read operations.

If you're on Windows you might want to give this a read https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I can think of better ways to have two programs communicate, than sending Lua scripts through files.
Also I'm not sure why you need two applications here, why not add whatever applicaton 2 does to application 1 as a library?

Comment: The reason why I need two programs here is the two programs running in the different places.   Lua sender will send lua file every 7 seconds. It knows every function params at the send time.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to tell my script needs to be reorganized every 7s based on the last result returned.